# HSSFWorkbook - Writing excel data with separate column for different values

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to fetch data from mysql and write it into excelwith some condition like below,

```
 List<DataClass> getdata = reports.getReportData(); //This will return data from jdbcTemplate



deviceId    value  date
T01         59        2-sep
T01         67        3-sep
T01         78        4-sep
T01         79        5-sep
T02         68        2-sep
T02         69        3-sep
T02         75        4-sep
T03         70        2-sep
T03         78        3-sep
T03         80        4-sep
T03         89        5-sep
```

Sample code I am trying,

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Report");
HSSFRow header = sheet.createRow(0);

 int counter = 1;
 for (DataClass e : getdata ) {  
    if(counter != 1)
       if(getdata.get(counter-1).getDeviceId() != (getdata.get(counter).getDeviceId())
                      #here i want to create seperate column for different deviceId values


  HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(counter++);());
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue(e.getValue());
  row.createCell(1).setCellValue(e.getDate());

   }
```

I want to write these data into excel like below,

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class to save information about the position of the data:

```
class DataPosition {
    public Integer colNum;
    public Integer rowNum;

    public DataPosition(Integer colNum,Integer rowNum) {
        this.colNum = colNum;
        this.rowNum = rowNum;
    }
}
```

As you loop the data, you check if deviceId is already included in the excel. If it is, you use the last column and row number corresponding to that deviceId. If it's not included, then use the last column information to add a new device data and store it in the map containing the position of that data

```
Map<String, DataPosition> excelIds = new HashMap<>();
DataPosition position;
// Start at -2 so when it comes to the first value, you add 2 to place the column number to 0
Integer currentColNum = -2;
Integer currentRowNum = 1;
HSSFRow row;
for (DataClass e: getdata) {  
    position = excelIds.get(e.getDeviceId());
    if (position != null) {
        // Add a new row
        position.rowNum++;
        currentRowNum = position.rowNum;
    } else {
        // Add a new column (increments by two because you need two columns for the representation)
        currentColNum += 2;
        currentRowNum = 1;
        excelIds.put(e.getDeviceId(), new DataPosition(currentColNum, currentRowNum));
    }

    row = sheet.getRow(currentRowNum);
    if (row == null) {
        row = sheet.createRow(currentRowNum);
    }

    row.createCell(currentColNum).setCellValue(e.getValue());
    row.createCell(currentColNum + 1).setCellValue(e.getDate());
}
```

Comment: It is too late but it needed now. It works fine but when I add heading as deviceId and date in a new row then first row is missing in excel.

Comment: I want to show deviceId and Date as heading for each devices like shown in the excel images

Comment: Is it because of the `currentRowNum` initial value? I have edited the post